# Show multiple column on AMP carousel

Tags: carousel, amp-html

From what I've learned about `<amp-carousel>` it has only 2 types of carousel interface: `carousel` and `slides`, which you can see on the AMP example website. I need to create something like this, multiple columned carousel. Is AMP carousel able to achieve this?

[image: Regular carousel]

Answer (score 3):

You can't customize `amp-carousel` the way you want, you need to check out `amp-base-carousel` which allows you to set `visible-count`, `advance-count` and other useful properties.

[The documentation.](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-base-carousel/)

Example :

```
 <amp-base-carousel
  loop="true"
  height="450"
  layout="fixed-height"
  visible-count="(min-width: 1150px) 3, (min-width: 700px) 2, 1"
  advance-count="(min-width: 1150px) 3, (min-width: 700px) 2, 1"
>
  <div>slide1</div>
  <div>slide2</div>
  <div>slide3</div>
  <div>slide4</div>
  <button slot="next-arrow" class="carousel-next" aria-label="Next">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
  </button>
  <button slot="prev-arrow" class="carousel-prev" aria-label="Previous">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
  </button>
</amp-base-carousel>
```

With some style for the buttons :

```
.carousel-prev, .carousel-next {
          filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px #4a4a4a);
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          padding: 20px;
          background-color: transparent;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          font-size: 24px;
          opacity:0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a way, yes.
You can use the `slide` interface, in under each section, but 4 entries.

```
  <amp-carousel height="300" layout="fixed-height" type="slides">
    <div>
      <div class="blue-box"> 1 </div>
      <div class="red-box"> 2 </div>
      <div class="green-box"> 3 </div>
      <div class="yellow-box"> 4 </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="blue-box"> 9 </div>
      <div class="red-box"> 8 </div>
      <div class="green-box"> 7 </div>
      <div class="yellow-box"> 6 </div>
    </div>
  </amp-carousel>
```

I understand it won't be shifting with one entry at a time, but I suppose it would be near to what you want